# How to extract single record per product and boolean value based on join to table with multiple records?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a query to extract the product name and type.

Product:

```
id, productname
1, p1
2, p2
3, p3
4, p4
```

ProductType:

```
id, tid, pid
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 1
3, 2, 2
4, 3, 1
5, 1, 3
6, 3, 4
```

Type:

```
id, type
1, t1
2, t2
3, t3
```

To get product and type I write:

```
Select product, type
From product p
Left Join producttype pt on p.id=pt.pid
Left Join type t on pt.tid=t.id
```

Now I want to get 1 record for each product and show product name and typebool. Typebool must be such that if the product belongs to t1 or t2 then 1 else 0.

```
Select product, case when type in ('t1', 't2') then 1 else 0 end TypeBool
From product p
Left Join producttype pt on p.id=pt.pid
Left Join type t on pt.tid=t.id
```

This returns multiple records for same product. If I use distinct then it still keep the duplicate because bool will either be 1 or 0. How to write better sql to keep 1 record? May be write case statement in where clause?

Expected output is:

```
Product, TypeBool
P1, 1
P2, 1
P3, 1
P4, 0
```

So I want to get all products, and mark 1 against those that have type as either t1 or t2. Otherwise mark 0.

Comment: Please include the expected output.

Comment: Product 1 belongs to type 1, 2 AND 3 what is the expected result in that case?

Comment: You question doesn't make sense. Your logic is creating two distinct rows for p1, but you only want one of them in your final results. If a particular Product has two types that yeild different TypeBools which one do you want to get rid of?

Comment: I want to get all products, and mark 1 against those that have either t1 or t2. Otherwise mark 0

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the condition aggregate function to make it, use `MAX` with `CASE WHEN` expression.

```
Select productname, 
       MAX(case when type in ('t1', 't2') then 1 else 0 end) TypeBool
From product p
Left Join producttype pt on p.id=pt.pid
Left Join type t on pt.tid=t.id
GROUP BY productname
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f76bd045573c2c3c7144604b5a1f53a0)